# Cron Job configuration error

Tags: wordpress, cron-job

i use wordpress 4.2.2 and civiCrm 4.6.3.
I have created a file CiviCron.php:

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.auroratrezzo.it/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm//bin/cron.php?name=user&pass=password&key=key-site");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have configurated cPanel cron job:

```
php /home/informac/CiviCron.php
```

I recived this error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Function name must be a string in <b>/home/informac/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/section-widget/olt-checklist/loader.php</b> on line <b>64</b><br />
```

Why ??

Marco

Answer (score 4):

The error seems to come from something unrelated to civi:

```
plugins/section-widget/olt-checklist/loader.php
```

Can you try to disable this plugin and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Another thought is to do this with wp-cli (WordPress drush equivilant).  This way you can tell wp NOT to load any plugins with fatal errors.

The standard syntax I use is:

```
wp --user=<cron> --url=<http://example.com> --path=</path/to/wp> civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

You can also do this to exclude plugins:

```
wp --user=<cron> --url=<http://example.com> --path=</path/to/wp> --skip-plugins=<plugin> civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

By adding --skip-plugin=  you can get rid of the nasty plugin causing the error.  Of course, removing plugins with fatal errors is preferred, but sometime we need to keep them around.

I have also added this to http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs

Comment: Nice tip Kevin!